# Static toroidal magnetic field rotating inside toroidal winding

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-circuits, electric-fields, electromagnetic-induction

what would happen if I took a toroidal core, generated a static toroidal magnetic field in the core and then rotated the core around it's symmetry axis within a larger stationary toroidal winding around the same core?
Just for simplicity imagine a toroidal transformer with a rotating core inside.

Would I get DC current generated in the stationary coil? If yes can anyone explain by what law and formula?